# Error in Loop when fitting models per patients

Tags: r, curve-fitting, nls

I am fitting a logistic growth model for each subject.

When I run my loop to fit the model for every patient. There is an error as some patients the model does not converge as they do not have a logistic growth. I want my loop to continue if there is an error in fitting the model and just have NA's in the dataset where I am capturing the coefficients

```
    growth_rate_l <- function(patient, data) {
  data0 <- data %>% dplyr::filter(pat== patient)
  fit0 <- nls(MRDRSLT ~ SSlogis(TIME, phi1, phi2, phi3), data = data0)
  t_doubling <- (summary(fit0)$coefficients)
  aic <-AIC(fit0, k=3)
  outdata <- c(t_doubling,aic)
  outdata
}

for (i in unique(doub1log$pat)) {
  doub1log$phi1[doub1log$pat== i] <- growth_rate_l(i, doub1log)[1]
  doub1log$phi2[doub1log$pat== i] <- growth_rate_l(i, doub1log)[2]
  doub1log$phi3[doub1log$pat == i] <- growth_rate_l(i, doub1log)[3]
  doub1log$AIC[doub1log$pat== i] <- growth_rate_l(i, doub1log)[13]
}
```

For some subjects the model will not fit and I get an error from nls

> ```
> Error in nls(y ~ 1/(1 + exp((xmid - x)/scal)), data = xy, start = list(xmid = aux[[1L]],  : 
>   step factor 0.000488281 reduced below 'minFactor' of 0.000976562
> ```

Once it errors the loop stops, but I want it to carry until the end and have NA's for subjects whose models cannot be fitted.

I tried "try" and "tryCatch" but it is not intuitive any ideas on how to deal with this issue?

````
I tried tryCatch(, error = function(e) { skip_to_next <<- TRUE})    if(skip_to_next) { next }  ``` i tired this in the loop above
````

I put this in the loop above but it is not working. I am unsure whether I need to capture the error in the loop or in the function.

I used to be a stata user and it had a command called capture which allowed a loop to run regardless of error.

Comment: can you show what you tried with `try()` and `tryCatch()` ?

Comment: I tried `tryCatch(, error = function(e) { skip_to_next <<- TRUE})

  if(skip_to_next) { next } `  ``` i tired this in the loop above

Comment: Can you integrate the information from that comment into your question ... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
growth_rate_l <- function(patient, data) {
  data0 <- data %>% dplyr::filter(pat== patient)
  fit0 <- nls(MRDRSLT ~ SSlogis(TIME, phi1, phi2, phi3), data = data0, na.action = na.omit)
  t_doubling <- (summary(fit0)$coefficients)
  aic <-AIC(fit0, k=3)
  outdata <- c(t_doubling,aic)
  outdata
}

for (i in unique(doub1log$pat)) {
tryCatch({
  doub1log$phi1[doub1log$pat== i] <- growth_rate_l(i, doub1log)[1]
  doub1log$phi2[doub1log$pat== i] <- growth_rate_l(i, doub1log)[2]
  doub1log$phi3[doub1log$pat== i] <- growth_rate_l(i, doub1log)[3]
  doub1log$AIC[doub1log$pat== i] <- growth_rate_l(i, doub1log)[13]
}, error=function(e){})
}
```

You need add na.omit in the formula and inlcude a try catch in the loop for it to work.
[Skipping error in for-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14748557/skipping-error-in-for-loop)
[Fit multiple Gompertz curves and skip errors in R (nlsList and SSgompertz)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35828768/fit-multiple-gompertz-curves-and-skip-errors-in-r-nlslist-and-ssgompertz?rq=1)